# Replacing non alphabetical characters & numbers with other special characters

Tags: regex, vb.net, replace

I am using the following code to take out anything *other than* **alphabetical characters**, **numbers**, **question mark**, **exclamation point**, **periods**, **parenthesis**, **commas** & **hyphen**:

```
MsgBox(System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace("hello to you's! My # is (442) 523-5584. @$%^*<>{}[]\|/?,+-=:;`~", "[^A-Za-z0-9]", ""))
```

I come up with this: **hellotoyousMy#is4425235584**

It should read like so: **hello to yous! My # is (442) 523-5584.?,**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add all characters to your negated character class (take note of the space character!):

```
MsgBox(System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace("hello to you's! My # is (442) 523-5584. @$%^*<>{}[]\|/?,+-=:;`~", "[^A-Za-z0-9 ?!.(),#-]+", ""))
```

(I also added a repeating `+` to your regex, so it can replace consecutive disallowed characters in one go)

Answer (score 1):

Add a space and other symbols in the regex:

```
MsgBox(System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace("hello to you's! My # is (442) 523-5584. @$%^*<>{}[]\|/?,+-=:;`~", "[^A-Za-z0-9 \(\)\!\.,\-\?]", ""))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Regex.Replace("your text", "[^A-Za-z0-9 ?!.(),-]+", "")
```

It [^A-Za-z0-9 ?!.(),-]+ will grab all unwanted characters following one after another and replace them by ""

Comment: I also gave you a point for helping out! Thanks, nichiporets.